# Speed up python loop processing packets

Tags: python, performance, cython, scapy

I spend the whole day waiting for a loop to exit without hope!. I know that python is not so efficient when it comes to performance as such I would really appreciate any speed-up suggestions to my problem.

I have captured a large number of packets (around 500,000) using wireshark and saved them to .pcap file. After that I read the packets from the saved file by using Scapy rdpcap() function and then I accessed each packet in a loop to extract the source IP Address. My code is as follows:

```
from scaly.all import *

srcList =[]
Packets = rdpcap("pcapfile")

for pkt in Packets:
    src = Packets[Packets.index(pkt)][1].src
    srcList.append(src)
```

Note: I have done some digging and I found that Cython is used to speed-up nested loop, but honestly I have no idea how to use that in my case. any insight would be great

Comment: Cython will only be faster if your bottleneck resides on your processor. It appears that your bottleneck is IO related. In that case, it doesn't matter how fast your native processor handles the code, your speed will not increase.

Comment: Well, you're looping over a list of packets, getting the second packet with equivalent to your current packet, and appending it's `src` to the list.  Are you sure you want to be doing this?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: Python is well suited to write software with excellent performance. Usually it's the algorithms that cause software to run slow(ly). Processing 500k packets definitely is nothing that should take all day.

Comment: I suspect the issue is on the line `src = Packets[Packets.index(pkt)][1].src` Since looping is `O(n)` and list searching is `O(n)` making it `O(n**2)`.

Comment: @JoelCornett Noted with thanks

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee every packet has four headers (Ehternet/IP/UDP/Payload) so "Packets.index(pkt)" get the packet, "[1]" means IP header, ".src" gets the src IP Address

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee, I think you mean making it `worst cast O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not misunderstanding your intention, you can simplify your code, that should also speed it up:

```
from scaly.all import *

Packets = rdpcap("pcapfile")
srcList = [pkt[1].src for pkt in Packets]
```

The difference between this solution and yours can be illustrated with a simple example. As you can see, the second function is more than 10 times faster.

```
In [1]: lst = range(100)

In [2]: def f1(lst):
   ...:     out = []
   ...:     for item in lst:
   ...:         out.append(lst[lst.index(item)])
   ...:     return out

In [3]: def f2(lst):
   ...:     return [item for item in lst]

In [4]: %timeit f1(lst)
1000 loops, best of 3: 221 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit f2(lst)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.61 us per loop
```

Comment: You should note that the implied loops in list comprehensions do the same thing that a Cython implementation would: push the loop execution into C.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and elaboration

Comment: @JoelCornett -- I don't know much about the internals, but isn't the speed difference caused by not having to call `append` and of the usage of `LIST_APPEND` instead? -- if you look at `dis.dis`

Comment: The speed difference comes from O(n**2) v. O(n) in the algorithm. It does not matter much who you write the loop.

Comment: @Ber -- You are right. The increase in difference is only seen compared to really small list (removed that example). So it seems to be a setup thing -- still not sure why exactly though.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the issue is on the line `src = Packets[Packets.index(pkt)][1].src` Since looping is `O(n)` and list searching is `O(n)` making it `O(n**2)`.

Perhaps the following would work too:

```
from scaly.all import *

srcList =[]
Packets = rdpcap("pcapfile")

for pkt in Packets:
    src = pkt[1].src
    srcList.append(src)
```

or

```
from scaly.all import *

Packets = rdpcap("pcapfile")
srcList = [pkt[1].src for pkt in Packets]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the IP source, tell scapy to ignore parsing anything after the IP layer with:

```
IP.payload_guess = []
```

Put this before the call to `rdpcap`. Scapy spends a lot of time going through each layer, parsing and extracting all that it can find. This is where most of the time is spent reading packets.

Also, consider changing `rdpcap` for `PcapReader`, which doesn't load the entire file. This does not necessarily speed things up but reduces the memory footprint.